# Hibernate não Exclui

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Boa noite galera...
estou aprendendo Hibernate e tive um problema:

consegui inserir, recuperar os dados do BD... Tive um contratempo que corrigi adicionando a seguinte linha de comando nas configurações da execução (RUN):

```
--add-modules java.xml.bind
```

mas na hora de excluir tive este contratempo!

segue meu codigo:

```
package aplication;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import Dominio.Pessoa;

public class Programa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("exemplo-jpa");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Pessoa p = em.find(Pessoa.class, 1);

        em.remove(p);

        System.out.println("Pronto!");
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

}
```

no BD tenho o registro, onde o Hibernate procura pelo ID 1 que é este registro abaixo:

> 1   -   algumacoisa@hotmail.com   -   alguem

quando rodo o programa ele nao elxclui e aparece 4 warnigs:

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING:
>   Illegal reflective access by javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions
>   (file:/C:/ws/AulaJPA/lib/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar) to method
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
>   WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>   javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions 
>   WARNING: Use
>   --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
>   denied in a future release

coloquei o comando mostrado no warning na configuração da execução:

```
--illegal-access=warn
```

ele retornou apenas um warning:

> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by
>   javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions
>   (file:/C:/ws/AulaJPA/lib/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar) to method
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)

depois pesquisando melhor encontrei o mesmo erro e a resolução seria o seguinte comando:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

beleza... rodei, e não apareceu nenhum Warning, mas não apagou do meu BD!

estou usando JDK 10...

estou baixando a ultima versão estável do Hibernate que suporta versão JDK 8+ pra ver se não é incompatibilidade!

alguém saberia me dizer o que se passa?

valeu!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente acrescentar um `em.flush();` após o `em.remove(p);`.

Quanto a essas *warnings*, elas são o resultado do conceito de modularização introduzida no Java 9. Muitos desenvolvedores de ferramentas que utilizam de *reflection* ficaram bem descontentes com essas mudanças que acabaram causando vários problemas inesperados. Apesar disso, pelo menos por enquanto, você não precisa se preocupar com essas *warnings*.

Comment: Realmente... o flush ou o commit resolveriam o meu caso!!! obrigado mais uma vez pela força! Fica a dica no entando que o comando "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" definido nas configurações do 'run' do eclipse remove esses warnings que eu obtive! valeu